# How do I choose specific mana?

Tags: android, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

I'm trying this game out on android, but I can't seem to pick what mana to tap when casting.  How do I choose which land to tap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tap the spell, it will cycle through available mana until you come to a combination you like to cast it.  Don't tap too fast or you'll double tap and end up casting it instead.